# Correction of Proof that if f:[0,1] is a continuous function and f(x)>2 with x being in [0,1) it is not necessary that f(1)>2

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Here's how I wrote it up:

To approach this consider an example of a continuous function which fails to satisfy f(1)>2 even though it satisfies f(x)>2 for x in [0,1).  My counterexample is a negative parabolic function starting from 0 and at f(1) it is 2.  This function satisfies the requirement that f:[0,1] is continuous and f(x)>2 if x is in [0,1).  The negation of f(1)>2 would be f(1) $\leq$ 2.  The above assumptions do not permit less f(1) to be less than 2 so equal would work since x=1 is not included in our requirement.

Is this counterexample correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is right, but you should be more explicit with your counterexample. What exactly is the function? A slightly simpler counterexample would be:
$$
f(x) = 3 - x
$$
since $x \in [0, 1) \implies f(x) \in (2, 3] \subseteq (2, \infty)$ yet on the other hand $f(1) = 2 \leq 2$.